# Eclipse UI on Linux dark theme

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, look-and-feel

I have been struggling with Eclipse look and feel on Linux (Manjaro 18rc) with GNOME as DM. On every dark theme applied to GNOME, other than Adwaita (the light verison) Eclipse UI does not look good/appealing (see image below).

I *kind of* know why it does that, my request is an method to solve that.

So far I have tried to modify the .desktop file, but to no avail.

More so, as an irrelevant detail, solving this problem may be a start for another UI problem, an different IDE based upon Eclipse (Xilinx SDK).

[Eclipse UI on any dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op7Y5.png)

[Xilinx SDK UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpBeM.png)

Comment: Have you tried the built-in option?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more details?

Comment: I would have pointed you to Preferences > General > Appearance, but I guess I was confused in thinking you *wanted* it to be in dark mode with the rest of your desktop. Still, there are other themes there that might work better than the default.

Comment: You want Eclipse with its standard light theme in a Linux with a dark theme, right? Eclipse uses native UI elements and colors in some places. Since Eclipse 4.8 `GTK_THEME` environment variable is supported which can be used to choose a Linux theme (in your case you have to choose here a light theme) for the Eclipse application only: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#gtk3-theme-override-support

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the theme through the Eclipse preferences by: Preferences > General > Appearance. Inside the Appearance menu should be a place where you can change the theme.

Comment: Yes, I know that option, but I want to keep the original look of the IDE, the white/light one, and I cannot seem to find the right theme. I was thinking that starting the eclipse with an explicitly selected theme (Adwaita in my case) would solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Two years later I am running into the same problem. In my installation of Eclipse, it is obviously using colors from my GNOME theme and unfortunately the editor is barely legible. Setting the theme through the Appearance settings does not overwrite anything.

I found the following works to force Eclipse to use the default theme at start-up:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita ./eclipse
```

If you want to use the dark variant:

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark ./eclipse
```

The only thing that remained problematic was the javadoc background. Hovering over a Java element would bring out a solid black box (black background with black text foreground). Luckily this setting was able to be changed through Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Java > Javadoc background.

What that means is that if you run into smaller color and UI issues after setting a theme through GTK_THEME, try manipulating the colors of individual elements in Preferences.